# i try to pass a string to a simple conversion function, but the function only gets the first character

Tags: c, string, type-conversion

The `conversion` function should receive a string (in this case a coulour) and compare it to an an other string (each of the possible colour) and then return a number relative to that colour.

This is the simple code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int conversion(char colour)
{
    printf("\n %s \n", colour);
    if (!(strcmp(&colour, "red")))
        return 0;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "orange")))
        return 1;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "yellow")))
        return 2;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "green")))
        return 3;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "blue")))
        return 4;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "white")))
        return 5;
    else if (!(strcmp(&colour, "black")))
        return 6;
    else return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char colour = "red";
    int n;

    n = conversion(colour);

    printf("\n %d \n", n);

    return 0;
}
```

when i compile it, i receive these warnings

````
prova.c:7:21: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type
      'char' [-Wformat]
       ``` printf("\n %s \n", colour);
                   ~~      ^~~~~~
                   %c```
prova.c:27:7: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing
      'char' with an expression of type 'char [4]' [-Wint-conversion]
      ``` char colour = "red";
             ^        ~~~~~ ```

  char colour = "red";
             ^        ~~~~~
````

It seems to me that the function only gets the first character cause of specified formats. How to I fix it?

Comment: Use `char *` for your function header like it suggests.

Comment: Function `conversion(char colour)` does not accept string, only one `char`. The definition `char colour = "red";` is also incorrect, try `char colour[] = "red";`

Answer (score 2):

`char` can hold only one character. You have to use arrays of `char` to deal with strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int conversion(const char* colour)
{
    printf("\n %s \n", colour);
    if (!(strcmp(colour, "red")))
        return 0;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "orange")))
        return 1;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "yellow")))
        return 2;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "green")))
        return 3;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "blue")))
        return 4;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "white")))
        return 5;
    else if (!(strcmp(colour, "black")))
        return 6;
    else return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char colour[] = "red";
    int n;

    n = conversion(colour);

    printf("\n %d \n", n);

    return 0;
}
```